# How to I make my custom mySQL query to in rails 3?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Im trying to display recently added comments from tattoos a user has posted. So If I posted a tattoo, and then user_b posted "hey I like your tattoo" then Im trying to get just the comment.

First of all Im using the acts_as_commentable_with_threading gem which doesnt create a foreign key for the table im trying to join. So my controller cant look for tattoo_id, it has to look for commentable_id

In the controller I would have to call the Comment model and then pass some SQL stuff into it but apparently I have no clue how to pass custom SQL queries into ruby because even tho my query string works in terminal, I get all sorts of nonsense when trying to use it in rails.

Im basically trying to do this:

```
SELECT comments.id FROM comments,tattoos WHERE commentable_id = tattoos.id AND 
tattoos.member_id = #{current_user}
```

where #{current_user} will be the current_user passed in.

Comment: Do not use `#{current_user}`. See [SQL Injection](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#sql-injection).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think Ben's approach is best but for future reference if you do come across something more complicated you can always use sql for example:

```
Comment.find_by_sql("SELECT comments.* FROM comments,tattoos WHERE commentable_id = tattoos.id AND tattoos.member_id = ?", current_user)
```

Answer (score 7):

You don't have to jump through so many hoops to accomplish this. `acts_as_commentable` assigns a polymorphic association, so you should set it up like this:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Tattoo < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class User
  has_many comments
end
```

Then you can access the association as usual:

```
Tattoo.where(:member_id => current_user).first.comments
```

See http://railscasts.com/episodes/154-polymorphic-association for a general tutorial on how polymorphic associations work. It just so happens that this railscast uses exactly :commentable as the polymorphic example, so you should be able to follow along directly if you want.

Comment: well, acts_as_commentable makes the comment model belong to the commenter (the user leaving the comment) so that wont work. BUT that does clarify Rails and SQL for me anyway. thanks!

Comment: well, the way acts_as_commentable_on works is that the comment model belongs to whatever you assign it to, in this case the user. But you designate a separate model (or the same if you want) as commentable, in my case a tattoo, to be commented on. Acts_as_commentable then assigns the "commentable_id" column to reference what was commented, the tattoo. Sorry, I need to take the time to proof read my questions and posts in the future